# Holding Tango Instance on Android Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, google-project-tango, orientation-changes

In my android app, I have an instance of the Google Tango service interface that I would like to keep running, and not restart on every orientation change.

The constructor looks like this:

`Tango(Context context, java.lang.Runnable runOnTangoReady)`

I cannot use a `Fragment` holding its instance, since this will lead to memory leaks, as the `Tango` instance keeps a reference to the first Activity as a Context. 
From the Google Docs:

> Caution: While you can store any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context.

Is there a way you would recommend me to keep the service running on orientation change, without having to use `android:configChanges` ?

Why does `Tango` need a `Context`, when it is not a View, nor it's drawing directly in UI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate your `Tango` instance with application context, thus refraining yourself from leaking context.

[`Context.getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()):

> Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.